# How I can remove background color from image using GraphicsMagick?

Tags: image, image-processing, graphicsmagick

How I can remove background color from image using GraphicsMagick? I need to delete rgb(255,255,255) and rgb(254,254,254) colors from image and replace them to transparency.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you should tinker with fuzz -parameter to match #fefefe

`gm convert in.png -fuzz 3% -transparent "#ffffff" out.png`

Comment: If you are interested in just changing those two specific colors you can avoid the "-fuzz 3%" and just type "gm convert in.png -transparent "#ffffff" -transparent "#fefefe" out.png.

Answer (score -1):

Should comment but cannot.

```
gm convert -geometry 50x50! -background white -extent 0x0 +matte in.png out.jpg or
gm convert -background color -extent 0x0 +matte src.png dst.png
```

Comment: It doesn't work. The first solution resizes image without replacing colors. The second doesn't replace colors.

Comment: @Dmitry recommend rostok's answr. Just for addition, if you are using firefox, try this `gm convert +page alpha.gif beta.gif`. The +page removes the unwanted page offset and firefox should behave as assured. It  removes the background that prints around your image when it displays in that browser.